# UIRefreshControl in UICollectionViewController moves half of the movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6

I want to use `UIRefreshControl`, which is designed for `UITableViewController`, in `UICollectionViewController`. I added the `UIRefreshControl` as a subview to `UICollectionView`. It works properly, but it moves the half of the distance that I pull down. Therefore, it is difficult to pull down refresh control to update/refresh the content.
That's why I want to make refresh control to pull down exactly how much I pull down. 
Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Which pull to refresh libraries have you looked at/tried?

Comment: @PaulPeelen Maybe it's iOS 6's new `UIRefreshControl` class.

Comment: Yes, I tried tell this by using 'native' keyword. May be I should change it.

Comment: @H2CO3 don't ask me. at the time of writing it was not clear, you should ask exculuber.

Comment: I haven't tried `UIRefreshControl`, but you could use e.g. [`ODRefreshControl`](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl) and adapt the code to behave according your preferences.